# Overriding syntax highlighting for LaTeX defaults in vim

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, vim-windows

I am currently using default syntax highlighting for LaTeX in vim on a Windows machine. Here are the contents of my `_vimrc` file:

```
set number
set belloff=all
syntax on
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set ruler
```

Unfortunately, I don't really like the syntax highlighting for the underscore character `_`, and I would like to override this without overriding the general LaTeX defaults built into Vim.

How can I do this?

Comment: I believe you're referring to the syntax highlighting used for errors. By default, it is shown as a small red block.  This shows you there is a syntactical errors (you need to escape underscores as `\_`) Is this correct? If you're referring to something different, it would be helpful to see an image in your question.

Comment: Yes that's what im referring to

Comment: I posted an answer with more information about overriding this particular syntax group.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're referring to the red block shown in underscores without escaping (`\_`) or outside math context, then you need to figure out what is the syntax group used in that case.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36993989/460147), this is the code snippet to show you that information:

```
:let s = synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1) | echo synIDattr(s, 'name') . ' -> ' . synIDattr(synIDtrans(s), 'name')
```

Alternatively, if there are very few similar styles, you could scroll down the list after running `:syn list`.

In any case, the culprit seems to be the syntax group called `texOnlyMath`. Therefore, you can change it with a new file in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` with the following line:

```
hi texOnlyMath ctermbg=Blue ctermfg=Black
```

Obviously, this is just an example. You can change cterm or gui colors according to your needs (see `:h cterm-colors`, `:h gui-colors`)